# Highlight backgroung colors of some words in HTML Document in java

Tags: java, html, jeditorpane, swing-highlighter

I am reading HTML document as text and extracting matched strings(with start and end index) from documents based on string array.Now i have to change the background color of those extracted strings in the original HTML document.But i should not change the format of HTML file.

so i am using "javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter", which will not change the format of document.After highlighting, i am saving file locally, then view in browser to see the colors.I dont want to use any editors for this, as my intention is to view in browser.But thecolor changes are not reflecting here, i did not unserstand where was the problem.Here is my code sample.

```
public class TestEditer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BadLocationException {

     JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      String output;

     HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
     List<Pattern> patternList = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
     output = new Scanner(new File("C:/test.in")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();//26787.in contains HTML text

         editor.setText(output);

     Document document = editor.getDocument();
    String doc=  document.getText(0, document.getLength());
    System.out.println(document);
     String[] names={"Shannon","Sperling","Kim","Tammy","Nancy","Lana"};
     for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
        {
            String st = names[i];
         Pattern p= Pattern.compile(st);
         patternList.add(p);
        }
        System.out.println(patternList);

      for (int i=0; i<patternList.size(); i++)
      {
          Matcher matcher = patternList.get(i).matcher(editor.getText());
          int mStartPos=0;
          int mEndPos=0;
          while (matcher.find()) 
          {
                String matched = matcher.group();
                System.out.println(matched);
                mStartPos = matcher.start();
                mEndPos = matcher.end();
                System.out.println(mStartPos+" "+mEndPos);
                DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter =new DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
                editor.getHighlighter().addHighlight(mStartPos+1, mEndPos,
                        highlightPainter);
          }
      }
      //htmlKit.write(writer, editor.getDocument(),0,editor.getDocument().getLength());
      //String s=editor.getText();

      File file = new File("C:/data/file.in");
      editor.getEditorKit().write(writer,document,0,document.getLength());
     String s1 = writer.toString();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(s1);
        bw.close();
}
```

Comment: How you create color on input.txt file?

Comment: i was able to insert label, but i am not able to insert color into input.txt.

Comment: .txt file is not for rich text.

Comment: that is actually HTML i read it as txt file.

Comment: @Masud: could you please tell me where was the problem.

Comment: Is there any other way to save the styling in document. I tried to change colors using "SimpleAttributeSet".But i am struggling to save the styling in document.