# Save Color changes in HTML by using JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

Is it possible to read HTML text, add background colors(By using one of HTMLDocument or JEditerpane or HTMLEditerKit), save to file system and when i open in browser the colors should appear.I have tried with JEditerPane, set the text to editor and highlight the words based on offsets and write to file.But when i open the file in browser, the colors did not appear. So JEditerPane will not work in that way? or?

Comment: Show your current code

Comment: here it is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044777/highlight-backgroung-colors-of-some-words-in-html-document-in-java)

Comment: You don't chnage background there but just highlight some words. Open e.g. MS Word document, select some text, close and reopen the document. Selection is not stored. That's notmal flow. Add background attribute to model (Document) instead

Comment: How to load the file into "Document", i think it has some method like"SetCharacterAttribute".Do you mean the same or?

Comment: Use the jEditorPane.getDocument()

Comment: i get the document form "jEditerPane.getDocument()" and use "SetCharacterAttribute" method by casting to "defaultstyledDocument".But i get error like"Plain Document can not be cast to default styleddocument".If you had an idea could please give one example about changing background color in document level

Comment: After you set the html (kit or content type) you will have HTMLDocument which is instance of StyledDocument. Before the kit is set it's just PlainDocument for plain text

Comment: I tried in that way too.I have used "setCharacterAttribute" method on HTMLDocument instance, but there is a problem with indexes,the color are changing at someother indexes not at required indexes.